# ASP-Classic: Get error description into HTML tags

Tags: html, asp-classic

How to get error description from vb to html?I have tried below case which never works.

Code:

```
if err then
Response.Write " :Err Information==>>"          
%>
<HTML><table><tr><td bgcolor="#FF0000"><%=err.Description%></td></tr></table></HTML>
<%
End if
On Error Goto 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Normally, the script will stop execution on an error. To see what the error is , you have to use `On Error Resume Next` before the line that might raise an error and then check the `Err` object

Example:

```
<%
On Error Resume Next
Dim i : i = 1/0 'division by zero should raise an error

If Err Then
'or you can check 
'If Err.number <> 0 Then
%>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>:Err Information==>></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0000"><%=err.Description%></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<%
End If
On Error Goto 0
%>
```

More on Error Handling in ASP : [How To Create a Custom ASP Error Handling Page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300043)

Comment: Have you tested this? Please be more clear.It doesn`t work for me.

Comment: i have tested this and it is working for me. Which part is not clear ?

Comment: Just to extend this answer, you can also set-up custom error traps in IIS to catch your errors.  [This page](http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/custom-errors-error-pages-500-100-asp-classic-asp-and-iis-7-0) tells you all about catching errors in your asp pages and feeding them back.

Answer (score 0):

What [@SearchAndResQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682881/searchandresq) [doesn't mention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25658732/692942) is why your code is failing.

The issue here is Classic ASP will halt execution and return a `HTTP 500 Internal Server` to the client (depending on how the server is configured will depend how verbose the response is).

To stop execution halting when an error is encountered or manually raised using `Err.Raise()` use `On Error Resume Next`. This statement tells the VBScript runtime to jump to the next line when it encounters an error and populate the `Err` object.

To then capture this error check the `Err.Number` property to see if an error has been raised. Once you have finished use `On Error Goto 0` to reset error handling to it's default state (halting execution on error).

If you want to test multiple errors between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0` inside your error check (`If Err.number <> 0 Then`) use `Err.Clear()` to reset the `Err` object (`Err.Number = 0`).

```vb
'We are expecting the next statement to sometimes fail so try to trap the error.
On Error Resume Next

' << Statement here you expect to error will be skipped >>

'Check whether error occurred.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  'An error occurred, handle it here (display message etc).

  'Error has been handled reset the Err object.
  Call Err.Clear() 'Err.Number is now 0
End If
'Stop trapping errors
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and I thought posting that link was better than me explaining things. Not very good with words :)

Comment: @SearchAndResQ I'm not either just give a go.